# ui Datepicker - Format the Date after selection

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I am running an Ajax call to get places available for a certain date.

I can get that date fairly comfortably with the following code :

```
$('.booking-date').datepicker(
 {
   beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
   numberOfMonths: 2,
   dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
   showButtonPanel: true,
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { }
 }
```

I know the dateFormat is there, but I ideally want that to be in a nice neat format for the end user, Which produces something like : Sunday, 28 July, 2013

If I can switch the DateFormat for the dateText variable to a MySQL friendly date that would be even better.

Hope someone can help

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating the following :

```
onSelect: function()
{
 var dateText = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
 $('.date_hidden').html(dateText);
}
```